# perl6 Unable to initialize a state variable. Help needed

Tags: variables, state, assign, raku

I want to use a one-liner to print a middle section of a file by using a state variable to indicate whether the current line is within the desired section of the file. But I am unable to initialize the state variable. Initialization is so simple, and I just cannot find what the problem is. Please help. Thanks.

The file is name testFile.txt and has the following lines:

```
section 0; state 0; not needed
= start section 1 =
state 1; needed
= end section 1 =
section 2; state 2; not needed
```

And my one-liner is

```
cat testFile.txt | perl6 -ne ' state $x = 0; say "$x--> "; if $_ ~~ m/ "start" / { $x=1; }; if $x == 1 { .say; }; if $_ ~~ m/ "end" / { $x = 2; }'
```

And the output showed that $x=0 is not doing initialization:

```
Use of uninitialized value $x of type Any in string context.
Methods .^name, .perl, .gist, or .say can be used to stringify it to something meaningful.
  in block  at -e line 1
--> 
Use of uninitialized value of type Any in numeric context
  in block  at -e line 1
Use of uninitialized value $x of type Any in string context.
Methods .^name, .perl, .gist, or .say can be used to stringify it to something meaningful.
  in block  at -e line 1
--> 
= start section 1 =
1--> 
state 1; needed
1--> 
= end section 1 =
2--> 
2-->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me: Apparently, `-n` does not properly set up a lexical environment.

As a workaround, you can wrap the whole things in a block, eg by surrounding your code with `do { ... }` or even just `{ ... }`.

Also note that depending on your use case, the whole thing can probably be simplified by using the [flip-flop operator](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#infix_ff), eg

```
cat testFile.txt | perl6 -ne '.say if / "start" / ff / "end" /'
```

Comment: Thanks Christoph ! If you think it is a bug, then I am going to report it. I think Perl 6 is really cool and I really want to see it get better and better. My language preference in order: Perl6, Scheme(MIT, Racket), Perl5, Lisp(Clojure), and the rest (python, Java, C, C++, awk, Julia, assembly, etc etc).

Comment: I don't see why using a state variable shouldn't work, so please report it. There are some bits and pieces I'm not overly fond of, but on the whole, Perl6 is indeed a pretty nice language. Currently, it suffers from not having had a lot of real-world usage: it's still fairly easy to stumble upon compiler bugs, but with time, that situation will improve...

Comment: I'd say definitely a bug, as it works if you use `state $x //= 0` or `state $x is default(0)`.